# XSLT transformation validate XSI:type (or) element node exists

Tags: xslt

I have an input XML, which needs to be filtered if element node exists `'ns1:getGenResponse'` (or) validate with `xsi:type = "Gen"` of 'multiRef' element

If either one of the condition  successful then I can process `'multiRef'` records.

Input XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:getGenResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://service.pen.eewe.en.de>
      <ns1:getGenReturn xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="soapenc:Array" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[2]">
        <item href="#id0" />
        <item href="#id1" />
      </ns1:getGenReturn>
    </ns1:getGenResponse>
    <multiRef xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns2:Gen">
      <name xsi:type="xsd:string">ulm</name>
      <mail xsi:type="xsd:string">ulm@gmail.com</mail>
    </multiRef>
    <multiRef xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" id="id1" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns3:Gen">
      <name xsi:type="xsd:string">ABC</name>
      <mail xsi:type="xsd:string">abc@gmail.com</mail>
    </multiRef>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Trying with node exist 'ns1:getGenResponse':

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:response="http://tempuri.org/"
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  exclude-result-prefixes="soap response"
>
  <!-- Output -->
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <getGenResponse>
      <xsl:for-each select="//soap:Body[ns1:getGenResponse]/multiRef">
        <getGenReturn>
          <name>
            <xsl:value-of select="name" />
          </name>
          <mail>
            <xsl:value-of select="mail" />
          </mail>
        </getGenReturn>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </getGenResponse>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this XSLT, I can generate blank . I can't able to generate my desire output.

I am also trying to validate the data with xsi:type of 'multiRef' element node
with below code, but I am unable to execute the XSLT

```
**Trying to validate with xsi:type ="Gen"**

    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:response="http://tempuri.org/" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="soap response">

        <!-- Output -->
        <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

        <xsl:template match="/">
          <getGenResponse>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//soap:Body/multiRef[substring- after(@xsi:type, ':')='Gen']">
              <getGenReturn>
                <name><xsl:value-of select="name"/></name>
                <mail><xsl:value-of select="mail"/></mail>
              </getGenReturn>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </getGenResponse>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output expects:

```
 **Output Expected**
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <getGenResponse>
       <getGenReturn>
          <name> ULM </name>
          <mail>ulm@gmail.com<mail>
       </getGenReturn>
      <getGenReturn>
          <name>ABC</name>
          <mail>abc@gmail.com<mail>
      </getGenReturn>
    /getGenResponse>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: `ns1` is not defined in your input XML. That means, your actual input has an `xmlns:ns1="..."` and your sample XML here does not. You must have edited the sample too much.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, yes, I added that namespace now in Input XML but still issue with same XSLT, which i couldn't able desired output

Comment: You mention an "issue" in your comment, but not in the question. What is the problem with this XSLT? Is it failing with an error, or producing the wrong results, or what? And what is your desired output? And can you explain more about the requirement to validate with xsi:type="Gen"?

Comment: Hi Michael, I added now all information like expected output and the XSLT code validates with  xsi:type ="Gen"

Comment: Both your XSLT samples have errors in, although it is not clear if that is because you have shortened them for your question. The first XSLT needs a namespace declaration for `xmlns:ns1="..."` to work, and the second one would need `xlmns:xsi="...."`. Additionally, there is a rogue space in the function name `substring- after` which would cause an error. Thanks!

Comment: yes, you are right Tim, for first one I declared namespace xmlns:ns1="..." and it working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, I declared xmlns:ns1="http://service.pen.eewe.en.de" in the XSLT. now I am able to execute the code with desired result.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:response="http://tempuri.org/"
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  exclude-result-prefixes="soap response" xmlns:ns1="http://service.pen.eewe.en.de"
>
  <!-- Output -->
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <getGenResponse>
      <xsl:for-each select="//soap:Body[ns1:getGenResponse]/multiRef">
        <getGenReturn>
          <name>
            <xsl:value-of select="name" />
          </name>
          <mail>
            <xsl:value-of select="mail" />
          </mail>
        </getGenReturn>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </getGenResponse>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```